# Is it possible to clear/remove TapGestureRecognizer after tapped event in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I tried to apply this Image to be like ImageButton. Then I want to disable it after Tapped/Clicked event. By the way, I got some problems that I cannot Clear/Remove GestureRecognizers in Tapped event.

**This is my code:**

```
Image img = new Image { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Ns.ico.png") };

var tapImg = new TapGestureRecognizer();

tapImg.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{     
     img.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Ns.ico_disable.png");
     img.GestureRecognizers.Clear; //<--- this line is problem
};

img.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapImg);
```

How should I solve this problem but still the same purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Clear is a method call so your code should be `img.GestureRecognizers.Clear();`

Or you could make a Tapped method and unsubscribe from it when tapped

```
tapImg.Tapped += Gesture_Tapped;

void Gesture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tapImg.Tapped -= Gesture_Tapped;
}
```